# Permission denied for protoc on maven build in Teamcity

Tags: maven, ubuntu, docker, teamcity, docker-compose

I am trying to build a project using maven on teamcity and getting this error during maven build step.

> [Step 2/4] [ERROR] protoc failed output:
>   [Step 2/4] [ERROR] protoc failed error: /bin/sh: 1: protoc: Permission denied
>   [Step 2/4]  [13:03:14][Step 2/4] Failed to execute goal
>   com.google.protobuf.tools:maven-protoc-plugin:0.1.10:compile
>   (generate-sources) on project unit-protocol-lib: protoc did not exit
>   cleanly. Review output for more information.

Keep in mind I am using docker-compose for building the teamcity agent (agent running in container) and protoc is added to /usr/local/bin/protoc ($PATH has /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/bin/protoc has rwx permissions).

EDITED for ease

Forget everything above for a while.
I logged into the buildagent of teamcity server, access the shell using `/bin/sh` and execute the command `protoc` and it returns the error:
`protoc failed error: /bin/sh: 1: protoc: Permission denied`

Any help??

Comment: can your user execute the binary? `ls -lah /usr/local/bin/protoc` helps with that. Fix it with `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/protoc`

Comment: Post your `compose` and `docker` files.

Comment: Your build seems to depend on protobuf, which requires that you precompile some messages into class files, so they can execute swifter. However, the maven protobuf plugin does not contain the actual precompiler, but forks out to the command line to execute protoc (the compiler for protobuf). So your TeamCity server have protoc installed, but your build user gets permission denied. Once you solve that problem, the build will work. It is not related to any of the tags you specify.

Comment: could you please include the full text of the failed command?  I had the same issue and fixed it.  I may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

What I found was that the error message was misleading.

Here's what worked for me:

Try this:

```
protoc ./proto/hello/hello.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:./outputDirectory -I ./proto/hello/hello.proto
```

Parts of the command obviously look redundant, but this was what I had to do to get it working.  I recommend trying this, and see if it runs.  If it does then you can see if you're able to tweak it, but I don't think so.

if "." is your output, then do this:

```
protoc ./proto/hello/hello.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:. -I ./proto/hello/hello.proto
```

Notice that you don't need space.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the future (for someone like me who ran into this problem).

In folder with project in cmd:

```
chmod +x ./proto-gen.sh
```